# Dynamically created table cells not showing in Firefox 32.0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, css-tables

I have a game project where I used a dynamically created table.The table and its cells appears in Chrome but not in firefox.So,to check it I created a separate table in another html file to see if it's  a problem on my code or not, but again the table cells doesn't appears on Firefox. How can I solve this problem?

```
var table=document.createElement('table');
table.style.width='300px';
table.style.height='300px';
table.style.border='1px solid black';
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
   var row=table.insertRow(i);
   for(j=0;j<3;j++){
       var cell= row.insertCell(j);
       cell.style.border='1px solid black';

   }

}  
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

FIREFOX:

[image]

CHROME:

[image]

Comment: Works for me in FF33. http://jsfiddle.net/tt2gv7s3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some browsers don't show the cell border if there is not content in the cell. Try to populate the cell with a blank space at least

Comment: ok i solved it using a background color.As i want it blank :)

Comment: Next time you want to introduce a blank space use the html entity to do it: &nbsp;